# generic method which compares numbers

Tags: java, generics

> Write a method that compares 2 of any number (type restriction, class
>   Number) and returns a positive number - if the first number is greater
>   than the second, 0 - if the numbers are equal, a negative number - if
>   the first number is less than the second.

this is how I've tried o resolve the task

```
public class Numbers {
}
```

```
public class Comparator<T1, T2 extends Numbers>implements Comparable<BigDecimal> {
    private T1 obj;
    private T2 obj2;

    public Comparator(T1 obj, T2 obj2) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.obj2 = obj2;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo() {
         ;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo();
}
```

I'm totally lost with generics and this task, could someone explain the topic ?
What should be in class Numbers?
When should we use generic in class, method or interface?
What should i read?

Thanx

Comment: Hey! You are probably supposed to use [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

Comment: You can't compare any two numbers. `Number` isn't inherently comparable.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the 2 numbers are Numbers and Comparables. The `compareTo` method in the `Comparable` interface does exactly this, so you can just call that

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>> int compare(T num1, T num2) {
    return num1.compareTo(num2);
}
```

This requires both your arguments to be of the same type, be numbers, and extend comparable. The reason `Comparable` has a type parameter is because it should know the type of what it must be compared against, and there's no way for an interface to know the type of the class implementing it.

Comment: But then you've got to wonder: why use that method instead of doing the comparison directly?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this does what you want.  `Long`, `Double`, `BigDecimal` and
 other numeric classes all extend the class `Number`

```
MyClass<Double> d1 = new MyClass<>(2.0);
MyClass<Double> d2 = new MyClass<>(4.0);

System.out.println(d1.compareTo(d2));   // prints -1 since 2.0 < 4.0

MyClass<Long> l1 = new MyClass<>(23L);
MyClass<Long> l2 = new MyClass<>(23L); 

System.out.println(l1.compareTo(l2));   // prints 0 since 23 == 23

MyClass<BigDecimal> b1 = new MyClass<>(BigDecimal.valueOf(20L));
MyClass<BigDecimal> b2 = new MyClass<>(BigDecimal.valueOf(10L));

System.out.println(b1.compareTo(b2));  // prints 1 since 20 > 10
```

This class implements the interface Comparable to compare a
 value that extends the `Number` class.

```
class MyClass<T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>> {
    T val;
    public MyClass(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int compareTo(MyClass<T> cls) {
        // this works since each val that extends `Number` also implements
        // the Comparable class.
        return val.compareTo(cls.val);
    }
}
```